# Show that if the function $\phi:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb R$ is positive and Riemann integrable, then $\int_a^b \phi(x)d(x) >0$

Tags: real-analysis

"Given the two affirmatives below:

1) If a set $X \subset [a,b]$ doesn't have Lebesgue measure zero, then there exists $\varepsilon>0$ such that, for every partition $P$ of $[a,b]$, the sum of the lengths of all intervals of $P$ which contains points of $X$ is greater than $\varepsilon$.

2) Let $\phi:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb R$ be a function such that $\phi(x)>0, \forall x\in [a,b]$. There exists $\alpha>0$ such that the set $X=\{x\in[a,b];\phi(x)\ge \alpha\}$ doesn't have lebesgue measure zero.

Show that if the function $\phi:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb R$ is positive and Riemann integrable, then $\int_a^b \phi(x)d(x) >0$"

Obs: Consider $P=\{t_0,...,t_n\}$ a partition of $[a,b]$. For every $i=1,...,n$, we will indicate $m_i$ as being the infimum and $M_i$ as being the supremum of $\phi$ in $[t_{i-1},t_i]$. Evidently, once $\phi$ is positive, both $m_i$ and $M_i$ are positive, in every interval $[t_{i-1}, t_i]$. As a consequence, both $U(\phi;P)$ (upper sum) and $L(\phi;P)$ (lower sum) are positive. As $\phi$ is Riemann integrable, then $\inf_P U(\phi;P)=\sup_PL(\phi;P)=\int_a^b \phi(x)dx >0$. In other words: I don't see any reason to recur to the affirmatives to prove the problem. Please, I'd like to hear from you if I'm correct or mistaken.

Comment: The infimum $m_i$ of $f$ may be zero so that your argument does not apply.

Comment: Good afternoon, User. what you said makes sense. So, would you know how to solve the problem by using the hypothesis?

Comment: it would be much simpler to argue directly using the fact that integrability of $\phi$ implies that its continuous almost everywhere. In particular it is continuous at some interior point $c \in (a, b)$. And since $\phi(c) > 0$ by continuity it follows there is an interval $I$ around $c$ in which $\phi(c) > 0$. It now follows that that there is a lower sum of $\phi$ which is positive and hence the integral of $\phi$ is positive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\phi$ is positive, by 2) it's greater than $\alpha$ in a non-negligible set $A$.
By 1, every partition of $A$ has lenght greater than $\epsilon$. So, consider the function $\alpha\chi_A$ ($\chi$ is the indicator function). Clearly, $\phi \geq \alpha\chi_A$, and thus $\int_{a}^{b}\phi\geq \int_{a}^{b} \alpha\chi_A$.

But $\int_{a}^{b} \alpha\chi_A\geq \alpha\epsilon$. This is because the integral is defined as the inf of the sums on all partitions of $A$, and all of these are greater than $\alpha\epsilon$.

Answer (score 1):

The set $X$ appearing in affirmation (2) has positive Lebesgue measure $\epsilon$.  Therefore by affirmation (1) the partition intervals containing points of $X$ have combined lengths at least $\epsilon$. For each such partition interval we can chose a representative point which is in $X$, where the value of the function is at least $\alpha$. Hence the corresponding Riemann sum will be at least the product $\epsilon\alpha$.